# ini file can't be parsed to array

Tags: php

I am trying to parse an `.ini` file but get only the result from the `require_once` which is simple text string on `var_dump`.

```
$ini = require_once (__DIR__ . "/../languages/{$language}.ini");

$translations = parse_ini_file($ini);
var_dump($translations);die;
```

Returns `TEST = '123123' TEST2 = 'zxczxcz(false)` where `false` is the dump.

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "/../languages/{$language}.ini");

$translations = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . "/../languages/{$language}.ini");
var_dump($translations);die;
```

Second paragraph returns the same result. My ini file looks like

```
TEXT = '123'
TEXT2 = '456'
```

What is my mistake here ? Thank you!

Comment: [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) does read a file (instead of interpreting it as code and possibly throwing a syntax error).

Comment: I am using `parse_ini_file`. Or it use `file_get_contents` in the background ? I`ve watched few example in youtube and they all did it with `parse_ini_file`.

Comment: Indeed: [`parse_ini_file($filename)`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file)

Comment: Thank you! Found it and it was a typo ...